# I am trying to make my buttons clickable so I have a link to a website using h ref and button elements

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, href

I want my buttons to link to the actual websites I created: for example Joeys Auto

My portfolio website is: http://loriroberg.com/cssfinalproject/index.html#home
It has a button for JOEYS AUTO.
The website for Joeys Auto is http://loriroberg.com/final/index.html

How do I change this code:

```
<div class="w3-col m3"><button class="button4 w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px">Joeys Auto</button></div>
```

So that it will link up to JOEYS AUTO?

The following code is under MY PROJECTS section of my portfolio.

```
<h3 class="w3-center">MY PROJECTS</h3>

<p class="w3-center"><em>Here are some of the projects I completed.<br />
I will post more soon.<br />
Click on the links to view them on the web.</em></p>
<br />
<!-- Responsive Grid. Four columns on tablets, laptops and desktops. Will stack on mobile devices/small screens (100% width) -->
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-center">


<div class="w3-col m3"><button class="button4 w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px">Joeys Auto</button></div>

<div class="w3-col m3"><button class="button4 w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px">CSS3 2D Animation</button></div>


<div class="w3-col m3"><button class="button4 w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px">CSS3 Animation</button></div>

<div class="w3-col m3"><button class="button4 w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px">CSS3 3D Animation</button></div>
<!--<button class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px">LOAD MORE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For linking to other sites (e.g. linking to an external site from your portfolio) ,you'll want to use [HTML anchor tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).
You can use the following link:

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Joey's Auto</a>
```

If you are already on loriroberg.com, you can also use a relative URL:

```html
<a href="/final/index.html">Joey's Auto</a>
```

That will take you to `http://loriroberg.com/final/index.html`.
You can find more info on relative vs. absolute URLs in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: <div class="w3-col m3"><button class="button4 w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px"><button onclick=a href="http://loriroberg.com/final/index.html">Joey's Auto</a></button></div>

Comment: I should have been more clear. You should be using the anchor tags (`<a>`) **instead** of the button tags for navigation. If you want to make the anchor tags look like buttons, you can style them with CSS or with `style` attributes (what you are using, the `style="margin-top:64px"`). You'll want to get rid of all the button tags and just use the anchor tags like I laid out in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. I will take your advice because it works. Thank you.

Comment: If that solved your problem, then would you mind making that the accepted answer? There should be a check mark next to my answer that you can click to accept it.